# Symfony3: Set Session Attribute with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.1 and I try set a session attribute with AJAX. I saved something in the session before in a controller. Now I created a new controller for the AJAX request that looks like this:

**AjaxController.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class AjaxController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/addId/{id}", name="addId")
     */
    public function hideCookieMessageAction(Request $request, $id) {

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set('id', $id);

        $response = new Response();
        return $response;

    }

}
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.addIdButton').click(function {

        var id = 1;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addId/' + id,
            async: false,
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Couldn\'t add flat to wishlist');
        });

    });

});
```

I don't get any AJAX or JS error message. But if I look into the Symfony Profiler there is no new Session Attribute. I tried it with a cookie too and it worked. So I think it has nothing to do with a wrong AJAX call but with a wrong session handling in the controller.

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: seems all correct, try to refresh the page before check for the session attribute

Comment: Reload the page to see new session attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your browser's debug tool.

I assume you are using Chrome in Windows, `Ctrl+Shift+i` opens Chrome's debug tool, click `Network` tab, and then do your AJAX request (click the buttn `$('.addIdButton')`), then the debug tool will show a new record,  check the record if you request is really ok (status is 200 means ok otherwise it failed)